# Game screen freezes, goes to standby after a few seconds. Sound keeps playing

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, freeze, crash, gaming

I have an issue on my gaming machine with two games: When I play the game for a while, the graphics will just freeze to a still image. Then after a few seconds the monitor does not receive a signal any more and goes to sleep. At the same time the sound is playing just fine. The machine does not react to any keyboard or mouse inputs. Pressing the power button does not start a shut-down of the system as it usually does.

This puzzles me a bit as it sometimes happens soon after booting the machine from a cold state. On other occasions it happens after a while playing. The case definitively gets warm. The GPU is cooled with two fans, the CPU fan blows away from the GPU. There are two case fans up front, one in the back. GPU-Z tells me that the GPU temperature is in a reasonable range.

The system in question:

- OS: Windows 10 Professional
- Games:

  - Project CARS (via Steam)
  - ARK: Survival Evolved (via Steam)
- GPU: AMD Radeon R9 380 (manufactured by HIS, latest AMD driver)
- CPU: AMD FX-8320
- Screens:

  - Dell P2314H via DVI-D
  - (a different) Dell P2314H via DisplayPort
- Power Supply: Seasonic G Series with 550 Watt, should be able to support the whole thing just fine.

My guesses are: Heat, power supply, or software glitch.

Especially “ARK” is an early access game, it runs less smooth than any other game of the same graphics quality. While this happened with ARK only, I did not think of it too much, it is probably just that game. Now with “Project CARS” crashing as well, I am annoyed (I want to play that game!) and worried that there is a general problem with my system. ARK is very demanding as the graphics engine does not seem to be very optimized. So it puts a heavy load on the machine. “Project CARS” is set to maximum detail, perhaps that is a problem. I will test that next.

Heat should not be an issue as it just happened rather quickly. Same with power consumption which is basically the cause for heat. I can play “Witcher 3: Wild Hunt” on three 1920×1080 screens on “High” and the system is rock solid. Other games maxing out the system never crashed either.

What could be the reason for this weird crash?

Comment: Verify your system meets the requirements for Project Cars to ran out maximum detail, what you describe, simply indicates your settings are to high for your system though.

Comment: Okay, I'll try with less graphical effects. By why would the game crash like that? Shouldn't it just have a drop in framerates? It seems extremely liquid. GPU-Z tells me that the GPU load is 100% all the time, but I assume that every game does that if you do not cap the FPS somewhere. Shouldn't the game be more robust against insufficient computing power?